# Generate PDF document with data on Titanium DB

Tags: json, pdf, xml-parsing, titanium

I am creating a mobile app using Titanium.  I am using the titanium db which is sqlite.  This pdf needs to have boxes to structure the data and images that I am taking with the app as well.

I am assuming what I need to do is convert the data into json on titanium, upload it to a web server and insert into a mysql/phpmysql db and then use some sort of script that is out there will read the web db and create a pdf and send it back to the phone

is that right?

and if so...i need help with that whole process haha...any good tutorials on db upload to web db process?

Answer (score 0):

[Check the docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient), HTTPClient is what you need to use, its a standard.

First steps would be to create a web service on your server that parses your JSON formatting.  The bulk of the work you would have to do has nothing to do with Titanium, but here is the code for sending a JSON object to some web service with a POST from a Titanium App.

```
var xhr_getstep = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr_getstep.onload = function(e) {
    // Do something with the response from the server
    var responseBlob = this.responseText;
};
xhr_getstep.onerror = function() {
    Ti.API.info('[ERROR] WebService failed.');
};
xhr_getstep.open("POST", 'http://yourwebsite.com/yourwebserviceentry.php');
xhr_getstep.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

// Create your object with info on how to create the PDF
var objSend = {title : 'Amazing Title'};
xhr_getstep.send(obj); // Send it all off
```